# How to call a modal window on browser close or back button in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a `back` `button` on my page. on click of that `back` `button` following code executes.

```
        PageInformation InfoView = new PageInformation ();

        InfoView = (PageInformation )ViewState["PBLSave"];

        if (txtValidFPGTE18MQ1.Text != InfoView.FPGTE18.Q1.ToString() || txtValidFPGTE18MQ2.Text != InfoView.FPGTE18.Q2.ToString()
            || txtValidFPGTE18MQ3.Text != InfoView.FPGTE18.Q3.ToString() || txtValidFPGTE18MQ4.Text != InfoView.FPGTE18.Q4.ToString()
            || txtValidFPGTE18MQ5.Text != InfoView.FPGTE18.Q5.ToString() || txtValidFPGTE18MQ6.Text != InfoView.FPGTE18.Q6.ToString())
        {
            mdlPopupExtender.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            redirectUrl = "../UI/Summary_Page.aspx";
            Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
        }
```

here the `mdlPopupExtender` is my custom made modal Window. I want to execute this entire code and show this modal window on `click` of Browser `close[X]` and Browser back button. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the function name is RunOnClose

**In CS File**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
public static void RunOnClose()
        {
            PageInformation InfoView = new PageInformation ();

        InfoView = (PageInformation )ViewState["PBLSave"];

        if (txtValidFPGTE18MQ1.Text != InfoView.FPGTE18.Q1.ToString() || txtValidFPGTE18MQ2.Text != InfoView.FPGTE18.Q2.ToString()
            || txtValidFPGTE18MQ3.Text != InfoView.FPGTE18.Q3.ToString() || txtValidFPGTE18MQ4.Text != InfoView.FPGTE18.Q4.ToString()
            || txtValidFPGTE18MQ5.Text != InfoView.FPGTE18.Q5.ToString() || txtValidFPGTE18MQ6.Text != InfoView.FPGTE18.Q6.ToString())
        {
            mdlPopupExtender.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            redirectUrl = "../UI/Summary_Page.aspx";
            Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
        }
        }
```

**In aspx file**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                     window.onbeforeunload = function () {
                         $.ajax({

                             type: "POST",
                             url: "WebForm1.aspx/RunOnClose",
                             data: "{}",
                             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                             dataType: "json",
                             success: function () {
                                 alert('Funtion called!');

                             },
                             error: function () {
                                 alert('Funtion not called');
                             }
                         });
                     };
    </script>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work :( javascript function is not getting called.

Comment: @NiroshaDKalinga Which browser you are using?

Comment: I'm using IE 11. doesn't work in chrome too. error function is getting called for all other buttons on the page where as for Browser back button and close[x] nothing happens. @HamzaAnis